# will visual studio automatically download extensions when installed in another machine under the same account

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I will be getting a new machine soon but I am curious if my old VS extensions will be automatically installed - I don't want this as I want a fresh system to reconfigure

Answer (score 1):

It is controlled by [Roaming Extension Manager](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/roaming-extension-manager-control-and-consistency-down-to-the-last-extension/). It shows all extensions you have on another machine, but doesn't automatically download them.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want your extensions to follow you to your new machine. Your best bet is to disable Automatic updates before you log out of your old machine, as desribed on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/finding-and-using-visual-studio-extensions?view=vs-2017) page.

Once youve signed into your account on your new machine you can check your list of extensions. If it is empty, then install what you need. If it is showing your extensions from your old account then delete at will.